# Uploading paid and free versions of apps

Tags: android, google-play

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do I need to change the package name for the free version of my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195595/do-i-need-to-change-the-package-name-for-the-free-version-of-my-app)

I have a free and a paid version of an android app.

When uploaded to the android market. Does it matter about the package name being the same? As long as the title of the app is different?

Such as "APP FREE" , and paid version "APP PAID" for an example.

Comment: I didnt know it was another question like this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package name must be unique. Two apps with the same package name cannot exist in the Android market.

From the Android [Hello World Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html)...

> Your package name must be unique across all packages installed on the
>   Android system; for this reason, it's important to use a standard
>   domain-style package for your applications. The example above uses the
>   "com.example" namespace, which is a namespace reserved for example
>   documentation — when you develop your own applications, you should use
>   a namespace that's appropriate to your organization or entity.

Comment: So how would i go about changing the package for 1?

Comment: Just follow the instructions outlined here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195595/do-i-need-to-change-the-package-name-for-the-free-version-of-my-app/5195633#5195633