# You need to use a different package name because "com.***.***.***" already exists in Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

I am new to android app development and trying to upload an app to the Google Play console, an app which has already been uploaded to another Google Play console account. Now I want to deploy the application to the client's account, I unpublished the the app from the current account.

Now when I try to upload the application to the client's console I get this error:

> You need to use a different package name because "com.***.***.***" already exists in Google Play.

I have tried to change the application's package name multiple times by following the below link:

[Android Studio Rename Package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/android-studio-rename-package)

However, it still shows the same error.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17492667/google-play-says-you-need-to-use-a-different-package-name-why

Comment: Yes, had some issues with the android studio reinstalling it did the job.

Answer (score 3):

```
You need to use a different package name because "com...***" already exists in Google Play.
```

> When you create a new project in Android Studio, the
>   [**`applicationId`**](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id) exactly matches the Java-style package name
>   you chose during setup. However, the application ID and package name
>   are independent of each other beyond this point.

**Solutions**

It will be better if you change your [**`applicationId`**](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id) from `build.gradle`

```
android{
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "" //cahnge here
        minSdkVersion //
        targetSdkVersion //
        versionCode // //increse verssion
        versionName "" //increse verssion
    }

}
```

After that **clean-rebuild-run**.

**FYI**

Your app signing key is used to verify your identity as a developer and to ensure seamless and secure updates for your users, managing your key and keeping it secure are very important, both for you and for your users.

- You should create a new **jks file**.

Comment: i tried changing the application id but i still get the same error

Comment: @shabbirsaif create a new key store

Answer (score 0):

you need to change the `application id` inside gradle

PlayStore checks application id of apps. this should be unique,

```
android{
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.****.****" //cahnge this
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
    }

}
```

**After this Sync the project . Then**

```
1- Goto build >> Generate Signed Apk

2- Create new key store path 

3- Then enter keyStorePassword and Key Password and Create new APK
```

Comment: Reason for Down Voting answer ?

Comment: you have to create apk using new jks file. updating answer

Answer (score 0):

changing application ID worked for me

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "" 
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Open your project in android-studio and then refactor your package name to another name.
if your package name has a familiar name like com.company or com.name or etc , probably you face this problem again.use a unique name

Comment: sorry. but it isn't package name that matters, he needs to change application id in build.gradle.

Comment: @AliAhmed i write several project in android-studio and didnt see diffrent between package name and applicationId !. but you can change applicationId without change package name