# Android Apps Update in Google Play Store

Tags: android

This is my Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    package="com.pavelstudio.todolistplus"

    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="1.1" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".AddEditNotes"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".DatabaseConnector"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ViewNote"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I have a Android apps in google play store.
I want to update this apps.
I have changed my versioncode and version name.
When I upload my apps in google play store it shows a message.

You need to use a different package name because "com.pavelstudio.todolistplus" is already used by one of your other applications.

So what I do now?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195595/do-i-need-to-change-the-package-name-for-the-free-version-of-my-app

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17492667/google-play-says-you-need-to-use-a-different-package-name-why

Comment: You uploaded an APK that is signed with a different certificate to your previous APKs. You must use the same certificate.

How i can solve it now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to select the app in play store developer portal and select the option submit new apk. I think you are trying to create a new app instead of updating the current application.

Follow this steps: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113476?hl=en

Comment: You uploaded an APK that is signed with a different certificate to your previous APKs. You must use the same certificate.
How i can solve it.@Sandro Machado

Comment: you have to use same keystore file that was used before. you might be using new keystore.